# How to remove a specific character from the string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008

String like: `'C/123232323' or '/343434343443' or 'C2323232322'`

From the string i want to remove C and /

Tried Query

Select replace ('/1233434', 'C/', '')

The above query is working if C/ both is there. if / only there then the replace is not working. if C only there then the replace is not working. How to achieve for both condition

Expected output

```
123232323
343434343443
2323232322
```

Need Query output

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by nesting `replace()` like so:

```
select replace(replace('C/12341234','/',''),'C','')
```

Probably not the prettiest but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use two nested `REPLACE`:

```
WITH SampleData(string) AS(
    SELECT 'C/123232323' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '/343434343443' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'C2323232322'
)
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(string,'C',''),'/','')
FROM SampleData
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Patindex + Substring`

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50)='/343434343443' ---or '/343434343443' or 'C2323232322'
SELECT Substring(@str, Patindex('%[0-9]%', @str), Len(@str))
```